# No data is passed in the facade method parameter

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-9

I can't understand why the data is not transmitted in the custom facade (`Format`) method parameter. I'm doing exception handling for the API and using my visualization handler (`JsonExceptionFormatter`).

Interface `CanFormat`:

```php
interface CanFormat
{
    public function format($data);
}
```

Facade `Format`:

```php
class Format extends Facade
{
    protected static function getFacadeAccessor(): string
    {
        return \Hopex\VkSdk\Foundation\Format::class;
    }
}
```

Class `Format`:

```php
namespace Hopex\VkSdk\Facades;

class Format implements CanFormat
{
    private array $formatters = [];

    public function with(string $formatter): static
    {
        $formatter = new $formatter();
        if ($formatter instanceof CanFormat) {
            $this->formatters[] = $formatter;
        }
        return $this;
    }

    public function format($data): mixed
    {
        foreach ($this->formatters as $formatter) {
            $data = $formatter->format($data);
        }
        return $data;
    }
}
```

Exception render method:

```php
final public function render(Request $request)
{
    if (env('LOG_LEVEL') === 'debug') {
        dump($this->getMessage()); // added for test (next "dump 1")
        return new JsonResponse(
            Format::with(JsonExceptionFormatter::class)->format($this->getMessage()),
            $this->getCode()
        );
    }
}
```

Visualization handler:

```php
class JsonExceptionFormatter implements CanFormat
{
    public function format($data): array
    {
        dump($data); // added for test (next "dump 2")
        return [
            'type' => 'error',
            'message' => $data instanceof SdkException ? $data->getMessage() : $data
        ];
    }
}
```

It's dumps:

```
[dump 1]: "ApiException: User authorization failed"
[dump 2]: []
```

P.S. Other formats work without problems.

Comment: where is the Facade here?

Comment: @lagbox No, it's a facade. The class that implements the facade is shown above. I did not post the loading code and facade ads because this is a standard procedure (https://prnt.sc/YY4njuUPjx4I).

Comment: @lagbox The data variable is redefined in order to so that all the added formatters (with the help of with you can add an unlimited number of formatters) are applied (one on top of the other) to the input data.

Comment: all makes sense .. i would do some actual debugging and set a break point and walk through the execution so you can see the actual values being passed around

Comment: Not sure the fact it's a facade is really relevant here. Does it work if you instead do `app(\Hopex\VkSdk\Foundation\Format::class)->with(JsonExceptionFormatter::class)->format($this->getMessage())` it should have the same result ?

Comment: @apokryfos yes, the call through the container gave the same result

Comment: Then the issue is most likely in the `Format` class itself check whether there's no formatter appended before your `JsonExceptionFormatter` that could modify the data before it reaches that formatter